# How to load fixtures using Minitest and Rails 3.0.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit, minitest

I have a Rails 3.0.10 project using the minitest-rails gem (running in JRuby 1.6.5 == Ruby 1.9.2). I would like to use all of our existing Test::Unit test cases with minimal changes in order to start using Minitest. Right now I can run tests but many fail because fixtures are not being loaded. I have yet to figure out how to make that work. If I change ActionController::TestCase to MiniTest::Unit::TestCase then the fixtures function doesn't work. I've tried the links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628654/using-minitest-in-rails) and the links within that one without any success. So the question is how to continue using ActionController::TestCase with the MiniTest gem or how to switch to MiniTest::Unit::TestCase and have fixtures load.

Answer (score 0):

Please try upgrading to version 0.1, which is dramatically improved across the board. Stuff like fixtures actually work now.